# Including socket.io.js results in undefined 'require'

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I've just started with node.js and socket.io.
I installed node.js using the windows installer, resulting in the following install path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs
```

I used npm to install socket.io and managed to include this in my server file, which is located in my projects folder, under

```
D:\projects\node\nodeserv.js
```

I then included the socket.io.js, which is located under the same socket.io folder, under the nodjs folder.

However, when I try to open the HTML file containing the client code, I get an error in socket.io.js stating:

```
Undefined reference to 'require'
```

Can someone help me out and see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Wait... "Undefined reference to 'required'"? Are you mixing up "required" and "require"? (former doesn't exist as a method in nodejs)

Comment: @TomTasche you are correct, edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you need to get the socket.io.js file from the nodejs server.

So instead of an include, use an async call to get the file, like:

```
$.getScript('http://localhost:1337/socket.io/socket.io.js', function(){
    //You can now use the io namespace
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to check your spelling very carefully.  If you can post post some code to look at, we can probably tell you the problem right away.  More than likely it's a simple typo.

Comment: The first thing I learned when learning NodeJS was "never trust the compiler errors."

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are trying to run node.js from the browser. Node.js runs on the server with the node executable. When you open the HTML file in your browser, it will execute the Javascript on it in a non node.js environment.

Comment: I know, but shouldn't I be able to open a io.Socket from my client code?

Comment: Read the [socket.io documentation](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io) and note which code snippers are for the server and which are for the client.