# Socket io, where do I get the socket.io.js I need to give to clients?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't find socket.io.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689877/cant-find-socket-io-js)

Well when using socket.io you need to include the client side using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

But where do I find the "socket.io.js" I need to put into the /socket.io/ folder for the clients?

Comment: https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't find socket.io.js](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8689877)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client - more information on the best practice for serving the socket.io client js file can be found here: https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/How-do-I-serve-the-client

Comment: This is what I was searching for, thank you.

Comment: @Wingblade note that socket.io auto-generates this js file for you, hence you shouldn't need to download it to include it in your projects (just link to http://yournodeserver:nodeport/socket.io/socket.io.js)

Answer (score -1):

The socket.io.js file is generated and offered by the server, hence there's no need to provide it yourself.

If you're using jQuery, you can use the following snippet to get the file

```
$.getScript('http://localhost:1337/socket.io/socket.io.js', function(){
    //You can now use the io namespace
});
```

I struggeled with this myself and have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540358/including-socket-io-js-results-in-undefined-require) about it earlier on SO.

Comment: He meant, "where do I go on the Internet to download the file".

Comment: @Pointy, no he did not. There's no such thing as a socket.io.js that you can include at client side.

Comment: I did, I meant where on the internet, also there is something that has to be included on clientside. How else would the client know the functions of socket.io, like socket.on and so on?

Comment: @ValentinKrummenacher, you need to include it like in my answer, there's no file to be placed somewhere in a scripts folder.

Comment: So instead of http://localhost:1337 I put the IP of my nodejs server? Or of the webserver the html and javascript files of my game are hosted?

Comment: Yes indeed, you need to replace it with the IP to your nodeserver.

Comment: There is in fact a javascript file you can include - although they do recommend this method. See this page: https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/How-do-I-serve-the-client